# SQLite - No error when updating a deleted row

Tags: android, xamarin, sqlite, xamarin.android

I'm trying to force an error condition to test some exception handling by updating a row after it has been deleted using the following steps:

```
1. Load record into GUI
2. Pull .db3 file to Windows
3. Delete record with sqlite3
4. Push .db3 file back to Android
3. Save record from GUI
```

However, there is no exception thrown from `ExecuteNonQuery()` nor is there anything in logcat.

**Why, if for Step 3, the DB file is instead renamed an exception thrown, but not when deleting the record?**

---

**Update:** Deleting the record directly from the device with [**`sqlite3`**](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2730422) results in this same behavior.

**Note:** Samsung Galaxy Tab2 requires the PIE (Position Independent Execution) version.

Comment: It may be reading/writing from the journal file. Instead of steps 2-4,  write some extra code to delete the record and attempt the save. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209091/what-is-the-journal-sqlite-database-in-android for good reading!

Answer (score 1):

Updating a row doesn't throw any error/exception in sql.
when a row is not found in database update query does nothing and show no error/exception message.

Comment: I'll test this out. I prefer not adding code to break stuff when testing, since it requires changing it. I prefer introducing as *"real-world"* scenarios as possible, but for this I'll give **petey**'s suggesting a try (renaming the DB file gave an exception sufficient for testing the associated try/catch, so I didn't proceed further but am now interested in observing this behavior).

Answer (score 1):

The update query does not throw any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about the sql3 data provider. However, you would want to use a query function, not a non query for the delete. Get the rows affected by deletion in the query. And then throw and exception ad required for the scenario when no rows are returned.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery()` is called from the `Mono.Data.Sqlite` provider after a `delete` statement is ran from the `sqlite3` command line interface.